# Visual Studio 2022 - Debug.WriteLine not show in output

Tags: debugging

I'm having trouble displaying information from Debug.WriteLine() in Visual Studio 2022. My settings seem to be correct however still no output when debugging.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Biblio.Poli
{
    public class BaseBody
    {
        public virtual string Name{get;set;}
        public virtual float Longitude{get;set;}
        public virtual float Latitude{get;set;}
        public virtual void CreateBase(string Name, float Longitude, float Latitude)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("BaseBody - Name: " + Name);
            Debug.WriteLine("BaseBody - Localizatiozation: " + Longitude + " | " + Latitude);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Since you showed us that the flag "Redirect all Output..." is checked why do you expect output in the "Output Window"? Check "Immediate Window" for your logs.

Comment: It is also empty.

Comment: And you are sure it's executing this code? As from the provided evidence (code/screenshots) it's not obvious.

Comment: In the main function, it creates an instance of this class and calls the method.